# convergence of random variables in Lp

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

I want an example that $X_{n} \to X$ in $L^1$ and $Y_{n} \to Y$ in $L^1$ but $X_{n}Y_{n}$ does not converges to $XY$ in $L^1$. Also If $P(X=0)=0$ then $\frac{Y_{n}}{X_{n}}$ need not converges to $\frac{Y}{X}$ in $L^1$.

Comment: Is it allowed to take $X_n = Y_n$?

Comment: yes , we can take ..

Comment: So then you are looking for a sequence of random variables convergent in $L^1$ but not convergent in $L^2$? It shouldn't be too hard to cook up an example for that.